# Using arcade in an attribute rule: error "array type expected" (ArcGIS Pro)

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcade, attribute-rules

I want to do the following attribute rule in ArcGIS Pro:

Query the excavation `ID` attribute according to xxx.xxx.x / x.xx.x / xxx.xx.x / xx.xx.x **(e.g. Bhg.018.1 / B.33.2 / Lhb.28.3 etc)**. , i.e. the 2- or 3-digit range between the points:
If this range is 2-digit, then the two numbers are to be taken and supplemented by a preceding `19`. This results in a year of the 20th century.
If this range has 3 digits and begins with an `8`, the 3-digit number string must be preceded by a 1. This results in a year of the 19th century.
If this range has 3 digits and begins with a `0` / a number other than `8`, the 3-digit number string must be preceded by a 2. This results in a year of the 21st century.

Thats what I came up with:

```
function calculateYear(GrabungsID) {
 // Find the position of the first point
    var firstPointIndex = indexOf(GrabungsID, '.');

    // Find the position of the second point
    var secondPointIndex = indexOf(GrabungsID, '.', firstPointIndex + 1);

    // Extract the range between the points
    var range = substring(GrabungsID, firstPointIndex+1, secondPointIndex-firstPointIndex-1);

    // Check the length of the range
    var length = length(range);

    // Initialize the year variable
    var year = 0;

    // Check the length of the range
    if(length == 2) {
        // 2-digit range, add "19" to the beginning
        year = '19' + range;
    }
    else if(length == 3) {
        // 3-digit range
        if(startsWith(range, '8')) {
            // begins with "8", add "1" to the beginning
            year = '1' + range;
        }
        else {
            // begins with "0" or any other number, add "2" to the beginning
            year = '2' + range;
        }
    }
    return int(year);
}


calculateYear($feature.GrabungsID);
```

It gives me the error: `Error on line 3. Array type expected`

Do you know what I have to change? The `indexof()` function should also be able to deal with strings and the `GrabungsID` is defined as string.

Comment: What makes you believe `indexOf()` supports strings?  In some languages functions can work on sequences and arrays and strings are sequences, but `indexOf` works on arrays, period.  For text in Arcade, you want to use `Find()` or maybe `Split()` in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Arcade doesn't have all the functionality of Javascript that you're attempting to use in your script

- While JS indexOf can take a string, the Arcade [IndexOf](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/array_functions/#indexof) can only
  take an array.
- It also doesn't have the additional parameters Arcade doesn't have
  a substring function, but it does have a [Mid](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/text_functions/#mid) function. But what you really want to use here is the [Split](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/text_functions/#split) function to create an array and to take its second element.
- The [Length](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/geometry_functions/#length) function returns the length of a geometry. Use the [Count](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/text_functions/#count) function to get how many characters are in a string
- Don't use variable names that are [reserved words](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/guide/reserved/) (length, year)
- Arcade doesn't have a startsWith function, but has the [Left](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/text_functions/#left) function
- To convert a string to a number, don't use int, use [Number](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/math_functions/#number)

You should always test your script in the [Arcade Playground](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/playground/) to see how well it works. The new script editor gives you better pointers on what is wrong with your script.

Here's the updated script:

```
function calculateYear(GrabungsID) {
    var myArray = split(GrabungsID, ".");
    var range = myArray[1];
    var theCount = Count(range);
    var theYear;
    if (theCount == 2) {  
        theYear = '19' + range;
    }
    else if(theCount == 3) {
        if(Left(range, 1) == '8') {
            theYear = '1' + range;
        }
        else {
            theYear = '2' + range;
        }
    }
    return Number(theYear)
}

calculateYear($feature.GrabungsID)
```

Comment: If I use this expression, I get the error "Index out of bounds, script line 3", event though myArray[1] should work and get back the numbers after the first point. Do you know what could be cause?

Comment: Are there any records that don't have something after the first "."? You could add in a line to break if the myArray Count is less than 2.